# Is there log of filenames skipped when copying files in ubuntu and having clicked "Skip All" for errors?

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer, copy-paste, filenames

I've recently copied, via ctrl+c and ctrl+v, about 200GB of files from an external drive to my new Ubuntu machine. Because these files were from an old Windows machine, many of them triggered errors such as those relating to the file names being too large. For practicality's sake, I clicked "Skip All" so that my machine wouldn't pause the copying in order to inform me of these errors. Does Ubuntu save a log of these errors anywhere? I want to make sure that I haven't missed any important files.

Answer (score 0):

Though I know of no log on copy error, it might be easier to use a comparison tool such as free [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/meld/?platform=linux).

That said, it might take some time to examine a whole disk, so I'd start this operation when you're done for the day.

Comment: @J.Ubun: Can you run `find` on the old Windows disk? A quick(er) way to determine which files were skipped would be to run `find` on the source and destination directories, sort them, and compare them with `diff` (or possibly `comm`).